# While using freegeoip in recon-ng,i get error [!] KeyError: 'city'

Tags: freegeoip

While using freegeoip in recon-ng i got the following error,i havent add any api keys yet, that shouldn't affect it;but somehow i get the error code as following:

```
[!] KeyError: 'city'
File "/usr/share/recon-ng/modules/recon/hosts-hosts/freegeoip.py", line 28,in module_run.
```

Answer (score 0):

repo owner has been changing freegeoip to ipstack service due to the resource no longer being available. So you just need update the module.

**SOLUTION**

Download this compressed file : [recon-ng](https://bitbucket.org/LaNMaSteR53/recon-ng/get/93bb9a4fb50b.zip)

Then extract it and copy ipstack.py into recon-ng directory :

```
cd Downloads && mkdir recon
unzip -n -j LaNMaSteR53-recon-ng-get-93bb9a4fb50b.zip -d recon
cd recon && cp ipstack.py /usr/share/recon-ng/modules/recon/hosts-hosts/
cd Downloads && rm -rf recon
```

image proof

[image: image proof]